# How can I modify vcluster cpu memory and disk on Rancher?

Tags: rancher, rancher-cli, rancher-rio, vcluster

i been using vcluster for multitenancy, but ı would like to adjust
cpu memory and disk usage for my likings. But since there is a lot of
parameteres in the deployment.yaml and i am lost. Which parameters i should
be changing for this. Any help is appreciated!
And for now iam changing storage and limits field in the vcluster but iam not sure if it is valid.

```
 "values": {
    "storage": {
      "size": "{{disk}}"
    },
    "vcluster": {
      "image": "rancher/k3s:v1.26.0-k3s1",
      "resources": {
        "limits": {
          "cpu": "{{cpu}}",
          "memory": "{{mem}}"
        }
      }
```